# asp.net detect master file location change

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I moved the ASP.NET master files to a different directory using the Solution Explorer.

Is there a way to propagate this change to the .aspx pages so that the `MasterPageFile` references get updated automatically?

(This leads me to another question - if I change the namespace or name of a class is there a way to automatically update this change in all files that use this class?)

Thanks.

Comment: if you have ReSharper

Comment: its a manual process, unless you use any 3rd party utility, like Resharper

Answer (score 2):

To avoid renaming file path, you can just set maser page in web.configs.

```
<pages theme="Default" masterPageFile="~/Defaut.master">
  ...
</pages>
```

[Creating Master Page (MasterPage in Web.config)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/creating-master-page-in-Asp-Net-part-5/)

Comment: Great tip. However, I have several master pages.

Comment: If you have multiple master pages, you can group ASPX pages in separate folders, and create web.config inside each folder. Or in your case, you can make a separate folder with web.config, and keep the ASPX pages inside that folder (which use different master page than primary one).